# How can I Pivot this Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

My basic query

```
 ID           Days      Y   Type
3014    L;M;M;J;V;S;D   15  PDC
3014    L;M;M;J;V;S;D   16  PDC
3014    NULL            17  PDC
3014    NULL            18  PDC
3014    NULL            19  PDC
3014    NULL            20  Altern
3014    NULL            21  Altern
```

What i'm trying to achieve

```
3014 L;M;M;J;V;S;D L;M;M;J;V;S;D NULL NULL NULL NULL 15 16 17
```

My Sql

```
    select * from (select 
    FS.FieldStudyId,
    C.Day as Dayss,
    C.IDCourse,
    C.Type
from 
    FieldStudy FS,
    Course C  
where 
    Fs.FieldStudyId = C.FieldStudyId)d
pivot
(
  max(Dayss)
  for FieldStudyId in (select z.FieldStudyId from FieldStudy z) 
)x;
```

But I doesn't work

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 14 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14 Incorrect syntax near ')'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server does not allow subqueries in the PIVOT clause. You will have to employ dynamic SQL, or list them explicitly (static list).

e.g.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
select @sql = isnull(@sql + ',', '') + quotename(FieldStudyId)
from FieldStudy

set @sql = '
select *
from (
  select 
      FS.FieldStudyId,
      C.Day as Dayss,
      C.IDCourse,
      C.Type
  from 
      FieldStudy FS,
      Course C  
  where 
      Fs.FieldStudyId = C.FieldStudyId)d
pivot
(
  max(Dayss)
  for FieldStudyId in (' + @sql + ') 
)x;';
exec (@sql);
```

Although this shows you how to use a dynamic list of PIVOT columns, it doesn't produce the answer in your question because the question is not clear at all.  With a slight variation to pivot on the `IDCourse` values instead:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
select @sql = isnull(@sql + ',', '') + quotename(IdCourse)
from Course;

--select @sql;

set @sql = '
select *
from (
  select 
      FS.FieldStudyId,
      C.Day as Dayss,
      C.IDCourse
  from 
      FieldStudy FS,
      Course C  
  where 
      Fs.FieldStudyId = C.FieldStudyId)d
pivot
(
  max(Dayss)
  for IdCourse in (' + @sql + ') 
)x;';
exec (@sql);
```

You can get something like the below:

```
| FIELDSTUDYID |            15 |            16 |     17 |     18 |     19 |     20 |     21 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         3014 | L;M;M;J;V;S;D | L;M;M;J;V;S;D | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
```

But it won't give you the trailing `15...16...17` in your question.